# Find an array if array(XOR)array[1:] is given

Tags: logic, discrete

Consider we have array a, and second array b = a[1:](just first element of a deleted). We are given array c which is result of XOR, c[i] = a[i]*b[i] (0<=i<len(b)). Can we find array a if we know c ?
Also we are given a[0:7]

Comment: The question is not clear. Please add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple to prove that you can't.

`c` has one fewer element than `a`. If `c` represented the same information as `a` in a completely recoverable manner, you could compress `c` in the same manner, again and again, until you were left with one element. Clearly the transformation is lossy.

Going the other way, there is no unique way to pick a pair of numbers given their XOR. There is a solution no matter what number you pick as the first in the pair.

However, given `c` and any element of `a`, you can recover `a` fully. Given that `(x ^ y) ^ y = x ^ (y ^ y) = x`, and `c[i] = a[i] ^ a[i + 1]`, it is easy to unwind the values of `a` given any `a[i]`.

Without loss of generality, let's assume you're given `a[0]`. Since `c[0] = a[0] ^ a[1]`, we get that `a[1] = c[0] ^ a[0]`. Now you can find `a[2] = c[1] ^ a[1]`, and so on for all `a[i]`.

Comment: I am sorry,we have also first 6 elements of a, does it change anything?

Comment: @MoodyLover. The last paragraph says yes. You only need one element of `a`.